# Python Shows Only One Figure Output

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, matplotlib

I use the below given code. It works fine but shows only the last code's output. I want to see all figures when the code is run. How can i achieve this?

```
by_marry_data = data.groupby('Marital_Status')['Churn_Flag'].mean()

by_marry_data.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Churn Ratio')

by_income_data = data.groupby('Income_Category')['Churn_Flag'].mean()

by_income_data.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Churn Ratio')


by_gender_data = data.groupby('Gender')['Churn_Flag'].mean()

by_gender_data.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Churn Ratio')
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same script or cell you need to put `plt.show()` after each plot, unless you want the data to plot on the same figure.

```
by_marry_data = data.groupby('Marital_Status')['Churn_Flag'].mean()
by_marry_data.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Churn Ratio')
plt.show();

by_income_data = data.groupby('Income_Category')['Churn_Flag'].mean()
by_income_data.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Churn Ratio')
plt.show();

by_gender_data = data.groupby('Gender')['Churn_Flag'].mean()
by_gender_data.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Churn Ratio')
plt.show();
```

Comment: (Though technically you don't need it for the last one...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to draw *subplots*, for example as in: [Creating multiple subplots using plt.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html).

If you want to draw each plot in an horizontal row, you could use something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
by_marry_data.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Churn Ratio')

plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
by_income_data.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Churn Ratio')

plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
by_gender_data.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Churn Ratio')
```

Also, you can switch from horizontal to vertical swapping first two arguments in each plt.subplot calls above.

Answer (score 0):

Try as said below.

May be call `reset_index()` on each `groupby`.
Then get those dataframes and plot  (rough code. Not tested below)

```
by_marry_data = data.reset_index().groupby('Marital_Status')['Churn_Flag'].mean()
by_income_data = data.reset_index().groupby('Income_Category')['Churn_Flag'].mean()
by_gender_data = data.reset_index().groupby('Gender')['Churn_Flag'].mean()
```

Now get axis from first plot and assign further.

```
ax = by_marry_data.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Churn Ratio')
by_income_data.plot(ax=ax)
by_gender_data.plot(ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It fixed the issue. I have another question. How can i change the color of the outputs of plots? For instance when i run the below given code, it shows two blue bars whereas i want blue and red bars.


by_gender_data = data.groupby('Gender')['Churn_Flag'].mean()


by_gender_data.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Churn Ratio')

Comment: @FatihSeyrek great. You can set different color in plot function. something like  ax = by_marry_data.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Churn Ratio',color='green')
by_income_data.plot(ax=ax,color='red')
by_gender_data.plot(ax=ax,color='blue')